# slideToggle work on Jsfiddle, doesnt work on my website

Tags: jquery, wordpress, frontend

It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/wqvjgmzp/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scroller").click(function(){
        $(this).next('div.content-scroller').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Doesn't work here: http://serwer1521488.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpress/?page_id=7&lang=pl

has anyone idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes. Of course. I looked to the console. Wordpress added <p> tags to my script.

Comment: what you have tried ? where is your code

Comment: the next() method retrieves the next siblings. In your code you do not have siblings complying with your selector ('div.content-scroller') due to a wrong usage of divs (even jsfiddle highlights that there is something wrong with divs). Check your structure and make sure the element you are searching for is a sibling (i.e. is within the same container) of the element being clicked.